# How to I move All Items In Folder To Another Folder With A Batch Command

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I am trying to move all files and subfolders from one folder, to another folder using a batch command... So far I have tried this:

```
writer.WriteLine("move / y " + Application.StartupPath + @"\testfolder\*.* " + Application.StartupPath + "\"");
```

Basically I am trying to move all the items in "testfolder" to the base folder of my application using a batch command. Thanks

Comment: i am having a c# application write the .bat file

Comment: But your question is not about C#, correct? It sounds like you need the syntax for the `move` command?

Comment: @RufusL yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use this instead, it uses the "move" command in windows like you did.

```
MOVE c:\testfolder\* c:\applicationfolder
```

Applicationfolder as in your base folder for your application. If it doesn't work for you, you could also use the robocopy command.

```
robocopy c:\testfolder c:\applicationfolder /e
```

And also, if this is batch, whats this?

```
writer.WriteLine
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i am having a c# application write the .bat file with premade commands

Comment: @tadll122101 Oh. Well, you could use my answer still I guess.